# use of 'that' and leaving out 'that' in the sentence with a verb like 'give'

Tags: relative-pronouns

The relative pronoun 'that' can be left out in some cases.

> the box (that) he made was made out of wood.

but when a verb has indirect and direct objects, both can be refered by 'that'?
in other words, are following constructions possible?

> The box that she gave me was in black.(I gave her a box and the box was black. )
>
> The dog that I gave the box was small.(I gave the dog the box and the dog was small. )

and in both cases, those 'that' are able to be left out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The box (that) she gave me was <del>in</del> black.

Either way is OK.

> The dog (that) I gave the box *to* was small.

Again either way is OK. But if there is any concern for clarity, I would leave *that* in. This example could possibly be misunderstood that you gave the dog, not the box "The dog I gave...".

Comment: if i don't add 'to' after 'box', is it wrong??

Comment: If you give some physical thing, you need to specify a destination. To me it is rather nonsense without it.